# use a phone number to open any app in the smartphone?

Tags: flutter, widget, chat, phone-number, smartphone

As the title says , I wonder if there's a widget in flutter to use a given phone number in the APP to give the user the possibility to open any chatting app in his smartphone ?

More explanation :  when user click on a button, my app should show him a dialog to choice between all chatting apps on his phone, then when he selects the chatting app : my app should open for him the chatting app itself to use it with the phone number !

The chatting app could be WhatsApp or Telegram etc...

Thanks in advance!

as your asked , this the code that I have try it :

```
 _lanchAPPChat(BuildContext ctx) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: ctx,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesome5.whatsapp),
            onPressed: () {
              _launchURL("Testlink");
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesome5.telegram),
            onPressed: () {
              _launchURL("Testlink");
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesome5.qq),
            onPressed: () {
              _launchURL("Testlink");
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesome5.facebook_messenger),
            onPressed: () {
              _launchURL("Testlink");
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: So you what to show options of all the chatting app available and load the chatting app the user select with a predefined text ? is this what you're trying to acheive?

Comment: I don't think so ,
I just need to put a button , when user click on this button, the APP open for him a dialog to choice between all chatting apps on his phone, then when he select the chatting app : my app should open for him the chatting app itself to use it with the phone number !

the chatting app could be WhatsApp or Telegram etc...

Thank you for help!

Comment: Well add the code you have tried so far, according to stackoverflow's strict guidelines I won't be able to help you until you make the necessary changes and this question might get closed . Hope you understand.

Comment: Ok I will add my code!

Comment: @basudevnayak , here's the code but I don't have any idea of how to find the chatting apps that user using!
thanks for help agin!

Comment: well I am posting the answer wait for it!!

Comment: you will have to write code and specify every single plartform , or else you get a option of plartform to send , a bottom navigation comes out as it generally happen with all apps which one do you prefer?

Comment: sorry @basudevnayak ,I didn't understand what did you wrote !
Can you explain please!

Comment: So according to your code you have several button kind of thing in the app ui that open specific app , right ? Well doing that can be cumbersome as all different platforms require specific android intent and api , else you can put a single button that beings up a bottom navigation bar with all options of the app installed for messaging , usually you can see this when you press the share button on any app.

Comment: ahh ok ,
how can do a single button ?